# Angular JS Application Is Failed with Multi Post Request

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service from an AngularJs application. I am posting multiple requests to the service. With this request I am checking the user information.

This is the service that is throwing the error:

```
public bool cheekCreditScore(Credit_Crad credit)
{

    int i = 600;
    int j = 700;

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Credit_Score FROM Credit_Score WHERE Account_Number = '" + credit.account_number + "'", cn);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account_Number", credit.account_number);
    var value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(tbl);

    if (tbl.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        //message = ("Account  is not exist Under this Name");
        return true;

    }
    else if ((Convert.ToDouble(i) < Convert.ToDouble(value)) && (Convert.ToDouble(value) <= Convert.ToDouble(j)))
    {

        // message = "Application Successful We can offer you " + Value1 + "Pound";
        return true;

    }

    else
    {
        // message = "Your application is unsuccessfull ";
        return false;

    }
    //return false;

}
```

These are the errors I encounter:
[image]

Here is the script code in Angular JS Web Application and here is the I am posting multi request to Wcf Rest Service.

```
var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])
    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;

        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.Tittle = "";
            $scope.First_Name = "";
            $scope.Last_Name = "";
            $scope.Gender = "";
            $scope.DOB = "";
            $scope.Mobile = "";
            $scope.House_No = "";

            $scope.Streent_Name = "";
            $scope.Country = "";
            $scope.Post_Code = "";
            $scope.Occupation = "";

            $scope.Account_Number = "";
        }
        $scope.CeditCardApplication = function () {
            var ApplicationDeatils = {
                Tittle: $scope.Tittle,
                First_Name: $scope.First_Name,
                Last_Name: $scope.Last_Name,
                Gender: $scope.Gender,
                DOB: $scope.DOB,
                Mobile: $scope.Mobile,
                House_No: $scope.House_No,
                Streent_Name: $scope.Streent_Name,
                Country: $scope.Country,
                Post_Code: $scope.Post_Code,
                Occupation: $scope.Occupation,
                Account_Number: $scope.Account_Number
            };
            myService.ApplicationDeatilsCheck(ApplicationDeatils).then(function (pl) {
                console.log(pl.data)
                if (pl.data) {

                    //$scope.Account_Number = pl.data.Account_Number;

                    $scope.msg = "User information is correct  !";                    

                        };

            }); 


            myService.ApplicationCreditScoreCheck(ApplicationDeatils).then(function (p2) {
                console.log(p2.data)

                if (p2.data) {

                    //$scope.Account_Number = p2.data.Account_Number;

                    $scope.msg = "We can offer you £6000";

                } else {
                    $scope.msg = "Application failed !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                }
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.msg = "Application failed!";
                console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
            });


        } // <-- missing }
    }]);



app.service("myService", function ($http) {

    this.ApplicationDeatilsCheck = function (ApplicationDeatils) {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/CreateCurrentAccountCheck", JSON.stringify(ApplicationDeatils));
    }
    this.ApplicationCreditScoreCheck = function (ApplicationDeatils) {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/cheekCreditScore", JSON.stringify(ApplicationDeatils));
    }

});
```

[image]

Comment: If you have an exception message that tells you exactly that your issue is in the SQL being run on the service, what specifically makes you think your client or the fact that it's the second query has anything to do with it? Most of the code in this question is completely irrelevant and should be deleted. Please read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire purpose of using parameters is that you avoid string concatenation and prevent SQL injection. Your code is both passing a parameter and concatenating:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Credit_Score FROM Credit_Score WHERE Account_Number = '" + credit.account_number + "'", cn);
cn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account_Number", credit.account_number);
```

This is, obviously, wrong, since you are passing a parameter that your query does not even know of.

Just change your code to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Credit_Score FROM Credit_Score WHERE Account_Number = @Account_Number", cn);
cn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account_Number", credit.account_number);
```

Comment: @Mohammad That could only be if `credit.account_number` is `null`, in which case you need to use `DbNull` instead

Comment: Yes . It's null .but I do not know is it the problems with ado.net or angular js

Comment: @Mohammad It might be a casing issue (the property name is camelCase in c# and PascalCase in Angular, the opposite of what's normal). Did you check that angular is actually sending anything in that variable? Check the request data with chrome